# vNext for Windows installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield

Windows installer version 5.0 released long time ago. Will there be any future development on this or Microsoft is going to deprecate it?

I am asking this as we are creating many new installers based on MSI technology. If not MSI, what it's alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Installer hasn't had a roadmap in years. It's not deprecated either though.  It just is what it is and still works and is still supported.

There's been a half dozen attempts to replace MSI with the latest being MSIX but all of them fall short of what MSI can do.

MSI is still the best choice for most installers IMO.  (Been writing installers since 1997 and MSI since 2003.)

Comment: Thanks Christopher for your reply. I am already aware about you mainly DTF :).

Answer (score 3):

At FireGiant, we've taken to calling the Windows Installer (MSI) the "Anything Installation Engine". It is the only Windows installation technology that is powerful *and* flexible enough to install anything.

While I'd like to see Windows continue to invest in the technology over more constrained installation technologies, they don't *need* to.

This fact leads to the sole upside of a stable installation technology: They aren't messing with it. :)

Comment: Imagine the day when all of softare engineering is mature like other disciplines.  That's the little taste of sanity we get today.  Although I wish there were a few features tacked on.